# read multiple text files and write to one file in one column

Tags: python, file-io

I would like to do the following:

1. read multiple ascii files (*.txt) into memory. I need to *skip* the first 4 lines of each file. The integer values in these files are written unstructured and continuous line after line. The number of values per line can vary and is not important.
2. Once I have read all data in memory I need to write it to one single file and one value per line, i.e. one column. Before writing the values, I need to write 3 lines of header.

I need to have this as script which I can call from the terminal (Bash). I appreciate your help!

Comment: yes, and?  is there a question?

Comment: Show us two sample input file and the expected output

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but I came up with this:

These are my assumptions:

1. The "values" in each line of the text file are separated by whitespace
2. The output file will contain values in the order in which the files they are contained in were passed in. So, if the function's params were `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and `outfilepath`, then the values in `f1` appear first in `outfilepath` and the values in `f2` appear second in `outfilepath`, etc

Here is a function that does what you want under these assumptions:

```
def readwrite(infilepaths, outfilepath):
    with open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(threeLinesOfHeader + '\n')
        for infilepath in infilepaths:
            with open(infilepath) as infile:
                skipLines = 4
                for _ in range(skipLines):
                    infile.readline()
                values = itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.strip().split() for line in infile)
                outfile.write('\n'.join(values) + '\n')
    print 'done'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! There remains one more question for me: how can I skip the first 4 lines of each infile? Using four times `file.next()` sounds a bit inflexible to me.